# Count days between dates in two rows based on condition

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm writing query which has to select few infos. Below table:

```
ID  ID-Toner    Quantity    Location    Order_date  Send_date
1     2            1           55       20.01.2015  26.01.2015
2     2            1           41       22.02.2015  26.02.2015
3     2            1           35       23.02.2015  26.02.2015
4     5            1           77       25.02.2015  25.02.2015
5     2            1           55       25.02.2015  26.02.2015
```

I need to select all columns and additional column with number of days between two dates: Order_date and previous Order_date for location = ie.: 55.
Sample result should look like:

```
ID  ID-Toner Quantity Location  Order_date  Send_date  Number_of_days
 1     2         1       55     20.01.2015  26.01.2015       0
 5     2         1       55     25.02.2015  26.02.2015       36
```

How to select such a query?

Comment: Add the expected result.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***updated after clarifications in the PO***

let'say that it needs to do a sort of aggregation on data called ranking, that is a type of classification based on numbering in succession order tbale's rows.

In our case the order is given by the Orders dates.

This is a quite cross-dbms solution (date fields are suppased to be Datetime type and DATEDIFF is a function of MySql) so I think that you can adapt to your dbms quite easily.

You can try the sql on Sql Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/290e9

> **Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
    (`ID` int, `IDToner` int, `Quantity` int, `Location` int, `Order_date` Date, `Send_date` Date)
;

INSERT INTO Orders
    (`ID`, `IDToner`, `Quantity`, `Location`, `Order_date`, `Send_date`)
VALUES
    (1, 2, 1, 55, STR_TO_DATE('20.01.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('26.01.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (2, 2, 1, 41, STR_TO_DATE('22.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('26.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (3, 2, 1, 35, STR_TO_DATE('23.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('26.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (4, 5, 1, 77, STR_TO_DATE('25.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('25.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (5, 5, 1, 77, STR_TO_DATE('25.04.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('25.04.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (6, 5, 1, 77, STR_TO_DATE('25.06.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('25.06.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (7, 5, 1, 77, STR_TO_DATE('25.08.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('25.08.2015','%d.%m.%Y')),
    (8, 2, 1, 55, STR_TO_DATE('25.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('26.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'))
;
```

> **Query**

```
SELECT 
        ID,
        ID_Toner,
        Quantity,
        Location, 
        Order_date, 
        Send_date,        
        days_from_previous_order
FROM(
  SELECT 
        current_ID AS ID,
        current_IDToner AS ID_Toner,
        current_Quantity AS Quantity,
        current_Location AS Location, 
        current_Send_Date AS Send_date,        
        current_Order_Date AS Order_date, 
        previous_Order_Date,
        COALESCE(DATEDIFF(current_Order_Date, previous_Order_Date),0) AS days_from_previous_order
  FROM(
        SELECT 
              TabOrdersRanking_currents.ID AS current_ID,
              TabOrdersRanking_currents.IDToner AS current_IDToner,
              TabOrdersRanking_currents.Quantity AS current_Quantity,
              TabOrdersRanking_currents.Location AS current_Location, 
              TabOrdersRanking_currents.Send_Date AS current_Send_Date,        
              TabOrdersRanking_currents.Order_Date AS current_Order_Date, 
              TabOrdersRanking_previous.Order_Date AS previous_Order_Date 
        FROM(
          SELECT Orders.*, @rank1 := @rank1 + 1 rank
          FROM Orders 
          ,(Select @rank1 := 0) r1   
          order by location, order_date
        ) TabOrdersRanking_currents
        LEFT JOIN( 
          SELECT Orders.*, @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 rank
          FROM Orders 
          ,(Select @rank2 := 0) r2   
          order by location, order_date
        ) TabOrdersRanking_previous
        on TabOrdersRanking_currents.Location = TabOrdersRanking_previous.Location 
        and TabOrdersRanking_currents.rank - TabOrdersRanking_previous.rank = 1      
  ) TabOrdersSuccessionRanking
) TabWithDaysFromPrevious;
```

Comment: almost work, column 'lastdate' should show date of current order for location, not the latest date for location. It's hard to explain. 
Example: i ordered product 2015-02-10, previous order was 2015-01-1. Column 'days' should show difference between those two dates not the latest order date and previous.

Comment: If I understand you have simply add a where cause filtering on lastdate

Comment: Not exactly, in column 'lastdate' is showed latest date not date of order for that record

Comment: ok, you want an output as that you showed in the question after up to date it.. I've seen it after

Comment: Also I forgot to add that column 'days' should show proper difference (order date for record and previous order date)

Comment: Wow, looks complicated but my question is If that will work in OpenOffice?, I found that this program doesn't go well with aggregation

Comment: well, dbase I suppose.. I think that you have only verify dbase mechanism for providing rows numbering and FROM keyword on subselect supporting. About the functions useed in the query I think there aren't many problems..

Comment: the "at" (@) char is a symbol of MySql to designate an identificator as a variable.. I don't think that your dbms, or "dev" environment it is compliant.. you have to adapt the sql statements code in the sql code of your dbms/api/environment